# how to change visibity of imageview on click of listview item it does no work

Tags: android

holder.imgItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


             Toast.makeText(mContext, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.icon .setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain problem instead of just posting code

Comment: iam not able to change the visibilty of imageview which is in  the listview item.i want to make it gone on the click of listview item

Comment: on ListView row click or on `imgItem` Button Click? and are you able to see Toast message?

Comment: yes iam able to see toast

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: @AvaisShaikh: see my answer probably help

Answer (score 0):

> how to change visibity of imageview on click of listview item it does
>   no work

Do it as using `arg0` parameter of `onClick` method:

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    ViewGroup view=(ViewGroup)arg0.getParent();
    View iconView=(View)findViewById(R.id.<id of imageview>);
    iconView .setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the code like this, because it will always return the last item of list. So change the code like this may do the trick. This will give the reference to current list item.

```
holder.imgItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

         ViewHolder VH = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

             Toast.makeText(mContext, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            VH.icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.customgridview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BeanClass>
{
    Context mContext;
    int resourceId;
    Animation zoom;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    View itemView;

    ArrayList<BeanClass> data = new ArrayList<BeanClass>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<BeanClass> data)
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
    }


    static class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView imgItem,icon;
        TextView txtItem;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        itemView = convertView;


        if (itemView == null)
        {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imgItem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
            holder.txtItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgicon);
            itemView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
        }

        BeanClass item = getItem(position);
        holder.imgItem.setImageDrawable(item.getImage());
        holder.txtItem.setText(item.getTitle());

        holder.imgItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //zoom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                        //    R.layout.zoom);
                //holder.imgItem.startAnimation(zoom);
                   ViewHolder VH = (ViewHolder)  itemView.getTag();
                 Toast.makeText(mContext, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // holder.icon .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 VH.icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        return itemView;
    }

    }
```

iam not able to change the visibilty of imageview which is in the listview item.i want to make it gone on the click of listview item –